# How to classify shapefile data into groups?

Tags: qgis

I have a map with a shp file containing information on land use. The attribute table has over 10,000 rows.

I need to classify this information into 6 groups to represent 6 colors on my map. I know you can re classify by adding on a new column on the attribute table and put each row into the 6 groups, however this would take years to do 10,00 rows.

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Many thanks all

Comment: Welcome to GIS.stackexchange! Please provide more details on your data and an example of the classification criteria you intend to adopt.

Comment: It sounds like you are contemplating manually editing 10,000 rows. Have you thought about a field calculation?  What prevents you from doing that?  If not a calculation, then what about joining a lookup table--is there any difficulty with that solution?  (These are two of the commonest and most efficient solutions available in most GISes.)

Comment: I am not contemplating it, hence my post!

Comment: Whoops, pressed enter. I have never used either of the above, i have only just started using qgis. Which field calculation could i use to generate my new groups? In a nut shell, I have 25 subclass's which need to be condensed into 6 classes.

Comment: To repeat @steko's question then, how are you trying to classify them?  Is this something where you can select a group of them on a map, then use the field calculator to set an attribute?  Without knowing more detail about your data, and your goal, it is hard to determine what would work best for you.

Comment: Sorry for not adding more detail, I am a complete novice! I am currently classifying them by a particular attribute, however there are 25 groups in this attribute which need to become 6 in a new column. I have seen people using 'case' and 'when' formulas but i do not have these operators in my field calculator (located in the attribute table on the bottom row of icons). Hope the extra information helps, sorry if I have missed anything.....

Answer (score 2):

Case and when are currently only available in QGIS Master, which has some disadvantages for productive work.

I think you better make up a csv table outside QGIS, where you list the 25 group attributes in one column, and the 6 target ones in a second column. Supply field headers, add as delimited text to QGIS, and `join by attribute` your shapefile with that table on the first column. That should give you the 6 values in a new column.

Answer (score 2):

a possible solution:

1. open layer properties by right-clicking on the layer
2. choose style tab
3. choose **rule-based rendering** (left up; when you open style tab it's choosen single symbol renderer)
4. enter the first symbol and type in the first rule
5. enter the next five symbols in the same way.

Comment: +1 This is simpler than joining a delimited text file to the layer

Answer (score 0):

I have a map in which I am only allowed 4 color groups, but data is 10-15 groups.

what I have been doing is coloring 6+ groups one color so I end up with the 4 color groups allowed.

Would that be something you can do or does the Data all have to be the same?

Comment: While this does work, it's not as well maintainable as a rule-based renderer solution.